How to Print Humongous Allocations in a Java Program Without Using GC Logs?
I'm currently working on a Java application that makes use of humongous allocations and regions. Typically, I would monitor these allocations and regions using the GC (Garbage Collection) logs. However, in this case, I am looking for alternative methods to print out humongous allocations within the JVM, just like I can see the attributes of Eden/Survivor/Old Spaces in the memoryPoolMXBean.
GCLog:
G1 Eden Space memory used: 0 (0.0%)
G1 Old Gen memory used: 1077833728 (82.1%)
G1 Survivor Space memory used: 262128 (12.5%)
[0.905s] [info] [gc, start
] GC (2) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (G1 Humongous Allocation)
[0.906s] [info] [gc, task [0.907s] [info] [gc, phases
1 GC(2) Using 8 workers of 8 for evacuation
1 GC (21
[0.907s] [info] [g, phases
GC (2)
Merge Heap Roots: 0.1ms
[0.907s] [info] [gc, phases
GC (2)
Evacuate Collection Set: 0.4ms
[0.907s] [info] [gc, phases
GC (2)
Post Evacuate Collection Set: 0.3ms
[0.907s] [info] [gc, phases
] GC (2)
Other: 0.3ms
[0.907s] [info] [gc, heap
] GC (2) Eden regions: 1->0 (32)
[0.907s] [info] [gc, heap
GC(2) Survivor regions: 1->1(2)
[0.907s] [info] [gc, heap
GC (2) Old regions: 0->0
[0.907s] [info] [gc, heap
] GC (2) ArchIve regIOnS: 2->2
[0.907s] [infol [gc, heap
] GC (2) Humongous regions: 513->513
[0.907s] [info] [g, metaspace] GC(2) Metaspace: 705K(896K)->705K (396K) NonClass: 637K(768K)->637K(768K) Class: 68K(128K) ->68K(128K)
[0.907s] [infol [ac
GC (2)
Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (G1 Humongous Allocation) 1029M->1028M(1284M) 1.180ms

Here are the details of my situation:

I have a Java program that is experiencing humongous allocations.

I am familiar with using GC logs to monitor these allocations and regions.


Is there any way to print out or monitor humongous allocations and regions in a Java program without using the GC logs? Any APIs or techniques that can provide this information programmatically would be greatly appreciated.
Thank You

Why do you need the information? It would be helpful for context to understand why are you asking.

I don't think there are any APIs or tools that will provide this information programmatically.  (I might be wrong ...)  You can of course take a heap dump and query it, but I don't think the dump will tell you if an object is humongous or not.  And taking a heap dump has significant performance impact, to the extent that you would only want to use it postmortem, not for routine monitoring.

“just like I can see the attributes of Eden/Survivor/Old Spaces in the memoryPoolMXBean” Well, if you see an increase of the Old’s used memory without a preceding collection event of the Eden/Survivor space, you witnessed a humongous allocation. That’s possible to monitor with JMX. But it’s not clear what you hope to gain from that.

You can use JFR Event Streaming API to handle jdk.ObjectAllocationOutsideTLAB events programmatically. Allocations larger than a half of the heap region size are known to be humongous.
Here is an example:
import com.sun.management.HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean;
import jdk.jfr.consumer.RecordingStream;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class HumongousAlloc {

    private static long getRegionSize() {
        try {
            HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy(
                    ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(),
                    "com.sun.management:type=HotSpotDiagnostic",
                    HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.class);
            return Long.parseLong(bean.getVMOption("G1HeapRegionSize").getValue());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }

    private static void handleAllocations() {
        long humongousAllocationSize = getRegionSize() / 2;

        try (var rs = new RecordingStream()) {
            rs.enable("jdk.ObjectAllocationOutsideTLAB");
            rs.onEvent("jdk.ObjectAllocationOutsideTLAB", event -> {
                long allocationSize = event.getValue("allocationSize");
                if (allocationSize >= humongousAllocationSize) {
                    System.out.println("Humongous allocation: " + event);
                }
            });
            rs.start();
        }
    }

    static volatile Object sink;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(HumongousAlloc::handleAllocations).start();

        while (true) {
            int size = 1 << ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(24);
            sink = new byte[size];
        }
    }
}

